# How to show a page when mouse over on a menu?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, mouse

I'm trying to understand how this kind of menu works : [www.dantobinsmith.com/](http://www.dantobinsmith.com/)
How do you make the page associated with one of the menu items appear when you put your mouse over it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code base of the website I see that the developer has created the website primarily in JavaScript/JQuery where there is a full screen navigation that fades in the content when hovering on the correct navigation.

On clicking of the navigation item, the whole navigation is removed and the content appears at 100% opacity.

The website IS build oddly on Wordpress for backend editing, BootStrapper (getbootstrap.com) and JQuery and any additional javascript can be found here http://www.dantobinsmith.com/wp-content/themes/dts/app.min.js to inspect yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with css:

```
#input:hover { background-coler:blue; /*additional css for #input on hover */}
```

or javascript:

```
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('input').style.backgroundColor='Blue';">
<input id="input">
</div>
```